# Banach matchbox problem - small case check

Tags: probability

A chainsmoker buys two matchboxes filled with n matchsticks each.  Every time he needs a matchstick, he chooses one of the boxes at random and takes out a matchstick.  One day, he takes out a matchbox and finds it empty.  The probability that the other matchbox contains k (0<k<n) matchsticks is:

---

**My attempt:-**

I know this question has already been asked many times on this forum. However, I am not able to understand the solutions provided in their entirety. Thus, I tried to check it for a small case to verify if I am understanding the question correctly or not.

What I did in my initial case check was to assume n=2, which makes k=1. Now, that means the smoker would have picked 3 matchsticks out of the 4. This can be achieved in 2 ways:

**Case 1:** Choosing matchbox 1 (probability = $\frac{1}{2}$), picking up a matchstick from there (probability = $\frac{1}{2}$), choosing matchbox 2 (probability = $\frac{1}{2}$), picking up a matchstick from there (probability = $\frac{1}{2}$), and then finally choosing matchbox 1 again (probability = $\frac{1}{2}$), picking up the last matchstick from there (probability = 1).
Hence, the total probability comes out to be $\frac{1}{32}$.

**Case 2:** Same as case 1, only changing the order of picking matchboxes and matchsticks. In this case, it would be Matchbox 2---Pick a matchstick---Matchbox 1---Pick a matchstick---Matchbox 2---Pick the last matchstick left.

So, my total probability in this small case turns out to be probability = $2*\frac{1}{32}$ = $\frac{1}{16}$, which does not match with the final generalized function that people have reached in their solution.

Please help me figure out where the fault is in my interpretation of the question.

Comment: It would be better to identify a particular question whose solution you don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of picking A matchstick (e.g. ANY of the matchsticks) from a chosen matchbox is 1, because that's the problem statement. Once we pick a matchbox, we take a match from it (or try to) every time. Furthermore, when a matchbox contains zero matches, we need to pick it AGAIN for the game to terminate. You seem to describe picking the last match from a box. The problem asks for picking a box and seeing that it has no matches remaining at the time of picking it.

For this particular example you can think of it as 2 cases: 
(2 A's 1 B = 3 choose 1) A 
(2 B's 1 A = 3 choose 1) B

(3 choose 1)*1/16 + (3 choose 1)*1/16 = 3/8

Comment: While doing 3 choose 1, are we also not including the case in which we choose one matchbox only in the first 3 trials for example like A A A B or B B B A ? Can you please elaborate  what you meant by 3 choose 1 ?

Comment: sure. 3 choose 1 is simply the number of ways you can order/interleave 2 A's and 1 B. We do not include the case of "A A A B" because think about what would happen on the third A. The chainsmoker would take out matchbox A for the third time, and find that there are no matches left. However, there are 2 left in B. This does not match the described scenario.

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation ! :)